# Loop control using JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop

I saw the source code:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    counting: 
       for(int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
       for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         if(i == 9) break counting;
   }    
}
```

Now I implemented the loops as follows:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      counting: 
      for(int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
      {
         System.out.println(k);//to see how many times the outer loop runs 
         for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         {            
             if(i == 9) break counting;
         }
     }
}
```

I got that the outer loop runs once and the inner will run 9 times if I am not mistaken.
I have come to the conclusion that this is nested loops that has flow control implemented. All I don't understand is what is the role of `counting`?

Comment: `counting:` is a label.  What did you expect it to do?  Perhaps you intended to use `continue counting;` instead of break;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`counting:` is a label. When you call

```
break counting;
```

The code will jump to the end of the outer for loop.

Comment: It should run infinitely. My eclipse is disagreeing though...

Comment: The code will not jump to the label. It will break out of the loop labelled `counting`, which means jump to *after* the loop.

Comment: Yh just figured that out. I was assuming it would jump to the label... Updating. Java labels are confusing...

Comment: Its worth noting there is (deliberately) no GOTO in java, which is I think what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

It defines which loop is going to be stopped with the `break` statement. If you do not use a label, then the inner loop will be interrupted, but the outer one will continue normally.

Answer (score 2):

The `break` statement by itself lets you break out of a single loop; in most cases this is enough, but there are situations when you must exit from several loops at the same time.

Adding a label to a loop from which you want to break out and referencing that label from a `break` statement lets you end several nested loops at the same time.

The code from your post is not a good illustration; a better use case is a search in multidimensional array. Let's say that you want to find a pair `{row, col}` such that `array[row][col] == searchTerm`. You can do it like this:

```
int row = -1, col = -1;
searching:
for(int r = 0 ; r != MAX_ROW ; r++) {
    for(int c = 0 ; c != MAX_COL ; c++) {
        if(array[r][c] == searchTerm) {
            row = r;
            col = c;
            break searching;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should add : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

When you nested loop, if you want to `break` a `for loop`, you should define target to `break`, so you can you `label` to solve that.
for ex:

```
lb1:
for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
  lb2:
  for(int j = 0; j < 10;j++){ 
     for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
         if(a) break lb2; // this will break second loop
         if(b) break lb1; // this will break first loop
     }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can understand!

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        counting: for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
            System.out.println(k);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if (i == 9) {
                    System.out.println("I'm going to break!");
                    break counting;    // -----┐
                }                      //      |
            }                          //      |
        }                              //      |
        System.out.println("Broken!"); // <----┘
    }
}
```